# ¿Es posible encriptar datos en MySQL y desencriptar en CodeIgniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3, encriptación

¿Es posible encriptar los datos de una tabla en MySQL con la función AES_ENCRYPT, y poder desencriptar los datos por medio de la librería encryption de CodeIgniter?

tengo cargada la librería desde el archivo autoload y la llave de encriptación en el archivo config.

En mi controlador inicializo la librería con la siguiente configuración:

```
$this->encryption->initialize(
                array(
                    'cipher' => 'aes-128',
                    'driver' => 'openssl',
                    'mode' => 'ecb'
                )
            );
```

pero al intentar desencriptar los datos del registro con la instrucción:
`$this->encryption->decrypt($Registro->Campo)` me manda valores null

De antemano muchas gracias y cualquier ayuda será bien recibida.

Saludos!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, no puedes encriptar un dato en *mysql* y desencriptarlo en *Codeigniter*. Tendrías que encriptar los datos directamente en Codeigniter o en la base de datos.

Te recomiendo que si usas Codeigniter **NO utilices la librería [Encryption](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html)**, ya que está obsoleta y ellos mismos te piden que no la utilices.

Utiliza las funciones que proveen las versiones modernas de PHP, que son las recomendadas. (`password_hash`). Puedes encontrar más información sobre este método [aquí](https://php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php).

Un ejemplo para encriptar/desencriptar un dato sería el siguiente, solamente tendrías que copiar las funciones a Codeigniter:

```
// Encripta la contraseña y devuelve el hash.
public function hashPassword($pass) {
    return password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
}

// Compara el hash de una contraseña con la contraseña plana. Si coinciden devuelve true.
public function comparePassword($password, $hash) {
    if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```